# How to display an int without commas?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a list of Text views that include a year saved as an int. I'm displaying it in an interpolated string:

```
Text("\($0.property) \($0.year) \($0.etc)")
```

The problem, it adds a comma to the int, for example it displays 1,944 instead of the year 1944. I'm sure this is a simple fix but i've been unable to figure out how to remove the comma. Thanks!

Comment: So this is a localization issue, and maybe it should be left as is in many cases. Depending on the region of the device, 1000000 can be written like "1,000,000", but there are other variants like "1 000 000" for Sweden, etc.

Answer (score 26):

There is explicit `Text(verbatim:)` constructor to render string without localization formatting, so a solution for your case is

```
Text(verbatim: "\($0.property) \($0.year) \($0.etc)")
```

Answer (score 13):

Use `Text(String(yourIntValue))` if you use interpolation you need to cast it as a string directly. If you allow the int to handle it, it shows with a `,`.

So to recap.

```
let yourIntValue = 1234
Text(String(yourIntValue)) // will return `1234`.
Text("\(yourIntValue)") // will return `1,234`.
```

Comment: I did not know that. Cool!

Answer (score 7):

I use the built-in format parameter. It's useful for formatting well beyond just this one specific usage (no commas).

```
Text("Disk Cache \(URLCache.shared.currentDiskUsage,
 format: .number.grouping(.never))"))
```

Comment: I like this solution the best. It preserves the Text view's ability to support localisation and further numerical formatting. Surprised it did not get more upvotes!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/integerformatstyle/3766889-grouping/